# add spacing between matPrefix and matInput

Tags: angular-material, spacing, mat-input

I want to add some spacing in between the *matPrefix* and *matInput* of mat-form-field in angular. How can I targed them in css?

[image: see this image]

here's my code:

**.html:**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
     <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
     <input matInput required>
     <span matPrefix class="prefix"><mat-icon>person</mat-icon></span>
</mat-form-field>
```

**css:**

```
.prefix{
color: rgb(0,0,0,0.45);
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

As you can see, I tried adding class and then selecting the matPrefix with a class, it works fine with left margin, but now with right margin.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `mat-form-field-prefix` class with:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-prefix {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

or assign a class to your `mat-form-field` first and use:

```
.example-class ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-prefix {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a margin in input field. you need to reduce the input width. I have added class="username"

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
   <input matInput class="username" required />
   <span matPrefix class="prefix"><mat-icon>person</mat-icon></span>
</mat-form-field>

.username {
  width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried using css class, adding css styling to add margin to `right` side , but somehow it's not working. Although I am able to add margin to left side with the same property.

Comment: @MM1122: If you want to margin right side of input field, then you should reduce the input width. I have edited the answer. please check it

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and the below CSS fixed the issue for me

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
      padding-left: 10px;
 }
```